# why IPv4 in network connection details show difference from wireless network status connection?

Tags: networking, ip, network-protocols

the IPv4 address in **network connection detail** is: 10.10.10.129
but in **wireless network connection status** is: 10.10.10.138
(I use wifi to connect Internet, sorry I don't enough point to upload images)
Could anybody help I fix this problem? Thank a lot

Comment: Please post your ifconfig output.

Comment: @Karthikeyan: this is ipconfig in cmd:
               IPv4 address: 10.10.10.129
               subnet mask : 255.0.0.0
               default gateway: 10.10.10.10

Comment: So, what is the problem, seems wireless and wired both are connected.

Comment: @Karthikeyan: No, I only use wireless, not wired